# libjpeg: decompress & crop

Tags: c++, crop, libjpeg

I have the next standard code for JPEG image decompression which is based on `libjpeg`.

```
jpeg_decompress_struct cinfo;
// ...Set error manager and data source...
jpeg_read_header(&cinfo, TRUE);
jpeg_start_decompress(&cinfo);
while (cinfo.output_scanline < cinfo.output_height) {
    JSAMPLE* scanlines[1];
    // ...Set target pointer for scanline...
    jpeg_read_scanlines(&cinfo, scanlines, 1);
}
jpeg_destroy_decompress(&cinfo);
```

I want to read a part of the image, cropped by a rectangle:

```
// struct RECT {
//     int left;
//     int top;
//     int right;
//     int bottom;
// };
RECT cropRect; // Coordinates of the crop rectangle relative to the output image size
```

What should I modify in the code below to tell `libjpeg` to crop the image immediately?

This is how I can implement it:

1. Ignore first `top - 1` lines;
2. For each of the next `bottom - top` lines:
   1) Read scanline to temporary buffer;
   2) Copy pixels from column range `[left, right)` from temporary buffer to the target buffer.
3. Abort the decompression.

But this code is redundant.

Comment: It's redundant but simple. Unless you really *need* anything better, I'd stick with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performance-wise, especially if the original image is high resolution and you need a relatively small part of it, you should perhaps first [crop/trim the image losslessly without decompressing it](http://www.ben.com/jpeg/), which is possible at 16x16 px (8x8?) granularity and fast, and then decompress skipping just a few lines and pixels off the margins. You might also like this approach for smaller amount of memory in use for the operation.

If you are cropping just a bit, then the original plan to start decompressing in full is perhaps the best. There is almost no redundancy here.

Comment: Usually 16x16 is the best you can do. 8x8 is only possible when the image was encoded without subsampling in the chroma.

Comment: Thank you for answer, @Roman R. For now I will use the existing code, but it is interesting how to do lossless crop in `libjpeg`. In current scenario I will need over 50% of image width and 50% of image height, and the code will run on Android OS. As you know, there in not much memory on embedded systems.

Comment: @artyom.stv, since libjpeg reads one line at a time the memory overhead to read the full image size is negligible. You'll be throwing away the bytes around the crop area immediately as the image is read.